# Getting a HSDir Flag

Tags: flags, hsdir

How exactly do I get the HSDir flag?
I've read that that you get it, if the Node is accessible for at least 24 hours and it hosts hidden service descriptors.

But I'm still not sure, what is meant by this. Do I have to configure something for this or is it just a matter of time until that flag is set for my Node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little more complicated than "just a matter of time." You need the "Fast" and "Stable" flags, according to [ticket #8243](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/8243). According to [ticket #12538](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12538) the DirPort is not required anymore.

Comment: You need at least 96 hours uptime: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2242

Answer (score -1):

If everything is setup properly and you HS is running - it is a matter of time, if the network trusts you enough, you will get flags.

You can monitor your node here:

https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/

Comment: That's not true, or descriptive. In that it's not *just* a matter of time and it's not about *"trust"*.

Comment: You don't need to run a hidden service to get the HSDir flag either.